# urllib-like library that caches accordingly to HTTP headers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, web-services, urllib, microservices

I develop HTTP GET Webservices (REST) in a distributed microservices architecture.
For performance issues, I need the cache on the clients of the webservices.

Is there an urllib-like library that uses HTTP cache headers of the webservices to cache?

Note: requests-cache does not seem to read http headers

Answer (score 0):

Why we need to cache the HTTP headers?
Normally, only GET responses are valuable to be cached on the client.

Comment: I'd like to cache full response _according to_ HTTP headers, in particular the `Expires` field or the `Cache-Control: no-cache`